# RubyMine support for non-english Cucumber scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rubymine

I have my Cucumber scenarios written in German. RubyMine doesn't seem to recognize German keywords.

Anybody knows how to add to RubyMine support for non-english scenarios?

Comment: Does it work with the [EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP)?

Comment: I have a RubyMine 4.0.3. I will check RM 4.5...

Comment: Also check with 5.0 EAP.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for hint. That led me in to right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution for RubyMine 4.5.4 http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5468120?tstart=0
which is locking project to previous version of gherkin:

```
gem 'gherkin', '2.11.1'
```

For RubyMine Enoki (124.67) it works out-of-the-box without any changes.